# How to make only the 'set' function of a C# property private

Tags: c#, properties

Is it possible to have a C# class property

**ie:**     `public type name { get; set; }`

whose value you can alter within the private member functions of the class, but which can only be read by a client program (externally only the 'get' function is available)?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for declaring properties?

Comment: Yes. I assume the answer is there somewhere but I'm still figuring out how best to navigate MSDN Library entries. Reading them each line by line to find a very simple answer can get frustrating, even if it is getting easier the more I use it.

Comment: There is an expectation here that you do your research before asking questions, and not ask questions that you could easily find the answer to but that you just can't be bothered to search for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy, use `private`:

```
public type name { get; private set; }
```

They are methods, just like any other (albeit with pre-defined signatures), so access modifiers still apply

Comment: Awesome, I was hoping it would be this simple!

Comment: Note that this is only possible in C# 2.0 and newer.  Which hopefully by this point everyone can use.